how to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{m=-n}^{n}j_n(r)^2Y_n^m(\theta,\psi)^2$
I am wondering how to calculate   $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{m=-n}^{n}j_n(r)^2Y_n^m(\theta,\psi)^2$, 
where $j_n(r)$ is the Spherical Bessel function, and $Y_n^m(\theta,\psi)$ is the Spherical Harmonics.
There is a similar question link, but it is a 2D version, while this question is a 3D version.
I totally have no idea, and I wonder where can I learn these similar property, is there any book or website?
